# How to AutoSelect a result from DB on dropdown menu <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

I have this HTML:

```html
if (isset($listaGrupo)) {
$html = '<select name="subgrupox[]" class="subgrupo">';
$html .= '<option selected="selected" value="">Selecione</option>';
foreach ($listaGrupo as $value) {
    $html .= '<option value="' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_depto'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo_sub'] . '*' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '">' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '</option>';
}
   $html .= '</select>';
}

  echo $html;
```

**What I want is :** When the result comes from DB,the value in the dropdown should be auto selected.

[image]

My Ajax:

```js
function preencherGrupo(obj){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'url',
            data: {
                produto: obj
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".subgrupo").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Edit [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0YHt.png):
[image: With selected="selected"] 
Autofilled two dropdown menu with same information.

EDIT : @Diogo Cunha look the images :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 options.

**Option 1:**

When you execute this piece of code

```
foreach ($listaGrupo as $value) {
$html .= '<option value="' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_depto'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo_sub'] . '*' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '">' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '</option>';
```

}

you can add selected to the option for the value you want (or the last one)

example:

```
foreach ($listaGrupo as $value) {
         if($value == whatYouWant) {
            $html .= '<option selected value="' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_depto'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo_sub'] . '*' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '">' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '</option>';
            continue;
         }

         $html .= '<option value="' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_depto'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_grupo_sub'] . '*' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '-' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '">' . strtoupper(utf8_encode($value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_grupo_sub'] . '/' . $value['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_depto'])) . '</option>';
```

}

**Option 2:**

you can select the option you want inside **document ready** calling [jQuery prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

**Edit:**
I get what you want now, **you should not use css as a selector, it's a bad practice**, if you want some isolation between different select use a data-attribute like data-name or something and later in js call it like

```
$("[data-name='whatYouWantToChange']").JsCall
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, and I Already tried the Option 1, but in the other select box select the same result, I will add one Image for you understand ! PS: What you mean with : ($value == whatIWant) ?

Comment: i said inside document ready but in your case you may want to call in your ajax call

Comment: i didn't quite understand what do you want to be selected, if for example the DB returns 20 results, what is the one that you want to be selected?

Comment: Will come Only ONE result from DB, and I want to put it selected automatically, Understand now ?

Comment: i need more info about it. When do you call your ajax function for example?

Comment: I call the Ajax function on success of another Function passing the ID to make a search on DB all respective information about that product...
`select: function(event, ui) {
        preencherGrupo(ui.item.id);`

Comment: what you mean with ` if($value == whatYouWant) {` ? What should be this "whatYouWant" ?

Comment: ok, so you just tell me the data retrieved by your ajax function for your second select don't return 1 result but 1 or more result right? if the function returns only 1 result you don't need that $value == whatYouWant, you don't need a foreach you can acess data right away, if you need it you can allways only select the last value of "$listaGrupo" , in that case your whatYouWant would be the value in the position $listaGrupo.length -1

Comment: Look, everytime I click on the button "Produtos", it searchs what I put on the search box, and then brings all information for the respective field automatically. But I have a button " + " that add one more empty line to fills agains when I click on the button "Produtos" got it ? So, this select box changes everytime I click on the button "produtos" to make the search to ALL lines that have "<selects>"

Comment: I put two images for you understand.

Comment: this is wrong from the begging , tell me one thing , the php code you have is the code that returns data from you AJAX call?

Comment: i can't quite understand why you are using  $(".subgrupo").html(data) , you shoud just append new data to that selector, but you are replacing all the pre-existing data from "subgrupo", you should just use append or after instead of hmtl in your jQuery call, that's what is causing the trouble. But you should not append to "subgrupo" just put all selects in a div and append to that div, if you define a div like this : **<div id = "groups" >** you make the call like this :  **("#groups").append(data)** 
info about append [link]https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76198/discussion-between-diogo-cunha-and-edson-rodrigues).

Comment: Because my view "pesquisar_campos_grupo" separate the results ( 3 in just one field , that is "grupo, ds_grupo and depto" ) with " / " ... this each makes the loop to take these 3 info, got it ?